# Easiest way to display 10 colours in a small area

Tags: hardware

This question requires a bit of background.

I am building a resistor colour-band machine out of an egg carton. The idea is - *you are making a project. You are unsure of a precise resistance value you need, so you use a pot. Once you have the setting right, you take the pot, plug it into this machine and it gives you the 5-band colour code for the resistor you need.*

The trouble is how to display the colours in the egg-carton cups. I can come up with a few ideas - all flawed:

- RGB LEDs - *but how do you display black and brown?*
- LCD - *but where do you get a 2X2cm LCD?*
- Color wheel driven by servo/stepper - *but how do you make it fit?*

Can you think of any ideas that will work?

Comment: You should see how small they can make motors these days...

Comment: @ignacio-vazquez-abrams If you have an example of a small enough motor, why don't you post it?

Comment: http://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/dc-geared-motors/dc-gear-motor-ranges/nano-planetary-range

Comment: A DC motor seems a bit imprecise - I doubt it could rotate in 36˚ increments. Still, good to know.

Comment: Strap an encoder wheel to it.

Comment: You'd still have to fit 10 colours in 1 revolution - I doubt it could be that precise. What you really want is a tiny stepper or a servo, but I have been unable to find one small enough as yet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11977/discussion-between-felixphew-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you draw the colors on a piece of cardboard or similar material and use the LEDs to indicate which color is needed.  You only need to show the first 3 bands since they are for the resistor value, the others are for tolerance and reliability. Thus you would probably need a total of 30 leds, 10 for each of the first 3 bands.  But the LEDs could be  cheap red ones since they are only being used as indicators. If you want them to occupy a small area, place them in a circular pattern.

Comment: That's a good idea, but possibly not small enough. Nice concept though!

Comment: EDIT: I tried it, and it fits (just). Still seems a bit squashy, but a clever solution, so I ^1 'd it

Comment: I like your solution, but I would like some other ideas. Could you possibly ask anyone else to take a look at the question?